# How to recreate these physics style graph plots?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, wolfram-physics

The new graphs from [this blog post](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2020/04/finally-we-may-have-a-path-to-the-fundamental-theory-of-physics-and-its-beautiful/) look really nice in a dark background:

[image]

How to recreate the largest graph from [above](https://www.wolframphysics.org/visual-summary/dark/)?

**What I've tried**

Nothing yet... there is probably a link or notebook that has the code for this.

Comment: the graphs are nice, but the background being so dark is a horrible choice. `White as a background color emphasizes clarity and removes visual obstacles and clutter in today's trending use.`  (from google) and `white
The default background color for a web page in all other browsers is also white` white background is also easier on the eyes,. I think WRI is following some trends for no reason, that is all.

Comment: I like the dark. There's a light mode too though: https://www.wolframphysics.org/visual-summary/

Comment: [ResourceFunction - WolframModel](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/WolframModel) seems to have some functionality that can be useful for generating some of the graphs.

Comment: e.g., `wm=ResourceFunction["WolframModel"][{{x, y}, {x, z}} -> {{x, z}, {x, w}, {y, w}, {z, w}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, 10];
Graph[wm["LayeredCausalGraph"], AspectRatio->1, Background->Black]`

Comment: also `wm["StatesPlotsList"]` etc

Comment: The applicable styles should be listed somewhere in [`ResourceFunction["WolframPhysicsProjectStyleData"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/WolframPhysicsProjectStyleData).